# Is it acceptable to rerun an old coding challenge as a new thread?

Tags: discussion, duplicates, code-challenge

I ran [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/173209/robot-roulette-high-stakes-robot-gambling) a year and a half ago. It was a good time, and I want to run it again, with some additional statistical analysis on my end and some tweaks to the rules to clean up the format a little bit. Is it acceptable to re-post an old challenge?

It would qualify as a duplicate without a doubt, but in the context of a coding challenge that doesn't seem like it should necessarily be an issue on this site in particular.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## It Depends

In general, we handle reposting of challenges [on a case by case basis](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=repost). For this particular instance, I would argue that this KOTH challenge is OK to re-run, provided that someone can't just take the existing winner and re-submit it as a serious contender. In other words, there needs to be enough tweaking to the ruleset to make it a "new-enough" challenge, inspiring new strategies and new winners.

That's my general belief regarding KOTH challenges, too.

I would strongly recommend taking the challenge idea to the Sandbox for at least a week, so it can be ironed out and verified that it's not going to be a duplicate. You might also want to take some of the top competitors of the previous challenge and run a few scenarios to see if they'll again be top competitors.

Comment: Good suggestions, I will keep that in mind

Comment: I agree that a modified challenge should be allowed. Although some members of the community are keen to close duplicate-ish challenges. I’d recommend including a paragraph acknowledging the previous challenge and explicitly naming the differences.